# Resumable video upload to the Azure blob in Flutter application

Tags: flutter, azure-blob-storage, tus

how to achieve this?

I have tried tusc flutter packages. Everything has the same flow
like pushing the video chuck to tus server `https://master.tus.io/files`

I need to push the video source to the Azure blob directly without tus server.

Answer (score 0):

Use [resumable_upload](https://pub.dev/packages/resumable_upload) package for resumable file upload to Azure Blob Storage